# D3: Convert data to number

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, type-conversion, bar-chart

I have a bar chart in D3 and I want to display on the x axis some dates. What I get from the database are two fields which I have to concatenate to get the year and the month. See below. The idea is that for the d.date field i get NaN, although I have converted it to a number.

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = "20" + d.yy + "/" + d.mm;
    // coerce to number
    d.value = +d.value;
    d.date = +d.date;
    console.log(d.value);
    console.log(d.date);
});

x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    console.log("HEelllppp!!!!",d.date);
    return d.date;
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
})]);
```

Anyone with some ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a number using [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus):

```js
console.log(+"12345")
console.log(+true)
console.log(+"17.9876")
```

However, you're trying to convert a string with a character that's not numeric, like "2016/02". It will return NaN:

```js
console.log(+"2016/01")
console.log(+"1a2b3c")
```

Solution: use an ordinal scale for the dates, passing them as strings (lazy solution), or parse the dates using D3 (preferably):

```js
var dateString = "2016/04";//this is a string
var format = d3.time.format("%Y/%m");
var date = format.parse(dateString);//this is a date
var dateTick = format(date);
console.log("date is: " + date)
console.log("but you can show it as: " + dateTick)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but at the end i just want it in this format 2016/01. Do I apply another filter or something ?

Comment: If you're talking about the ticks, first you convert it to a *date*, then you use `tickFormat` to show the date the way you want. Check the last snippet again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to numbers, you should convert to *dates*:

```
var dates = data.map(function(d){ return new Date(d.yy + "/" + d.mm); })
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(dates))
```

If I use `var data = [ { yy: 2016, mm: 01}, {yy: 2016, mm: 02 }];` I get the following out of the `d3.min(xScale.domain())`:

```
Mon Feb 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: I just simply want this format 2016/01. How can I obtain this ?

Comment: You can use `d3.time.format("%Y/%m")` to format your date, e.g. `d3.time.format("%Y/%m")(new Date("2016/01/03"))` will just return `"2016/01"`.